# Why does WCF complain over identity check failure when service run under domain account?

Tags: wcf, service, identity, kerberos

When calling a WCF service got below error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The identity check failed for the outgoing message. The expected identity is 'identity(schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/rightpossessproperty:schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn)' for the 'http://server1.domain1.local/Service.svc' target endpoint.

**Binding:**

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="binding1">
    <security mode="Message">
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false" algorithmSuite="Basic256"/>
    </security>
     <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

**Endpoint identity:**

```
 <identity>
     <userPrincipalName value="testuser1@domain1.local"/>
 </identity>
```

**Note:** Service application pool run under `testuser1`. If service run under network service and client using `servicePrincipalName`, it works fine.

Any ideas?